# Windows 10 becomes slow after trying to open Pycharm or VSCode with Anaconda and does not recover unless restarted

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python, ide

I have been having trouble debugging this for a long time and do not know where to write the question.

I am using Windows 10 and have the latest version of Anaconda, Pycharm and an older version of VSCode installed. It might be important to mention that my projects are saved using Google Drive with the "Mirror Files" option enabled. Additionally, I have two different bank security programs always running in my computer in the background.

Occasionally (not always), right after turning my computer on and logging in, after opening one of the aforementioned IDE's on a project located at a Google Drive synchronized folder, the IDE will take a long time to fully open. For example, Pycharm will take an eternity to load the Git history information of a project.

When this happens, even if I close the IDE, the following weird things occur:

- Google Chrome takes ages to load a website
- The Task Manager takes ages to open
- Opening PowerShell takes ages to fully load (e.g. 1374000 ms)
- Typing Ctrl+Alt+Del seems to take ages for the computer to register the input.

Nevertheless, File Explorer continues being responsive. Nothing seems to hog the CPU when viewing the Task Manager.

There is nothing I can do to make Windows responsive again. Not even waiting.

The only way I found to "solve" this is by restarting Windows and hoping the next time I open the IDE, the same weird thing does not occur. I do not even know how to describe this. It isn't a crash, and isn't non-responsiveness. I guess "delayed responsiveness" could be the term?

There are so many variables at play here, that I do not know how to debug this. Some observations I have made though:

- the chance of this happening seems to decrease if my conda environments are up-to-date
- the chance also seems to decrease if I wait for Google Drive to finish processing the files
- additionally, the chance seems to decrease significantly if I wait for the bank security programs to finish whatever the hell they do after start-up.

---

**Edit** 1:

I updated VS Code, but uninstalled the Microsoft Python Extension, to only use it for LaTeX. I tested opening a project with Git integration inside a Google Drive synchronized folder many times. The issue does not occur.

The issue seems to be associated with Python (maybe Anaconda?) and Google Drive. In order to use the Anaconda environments with either IDE's, one has to run `conda init powershell`. I suspect that the batch file may be conflicting with Google Drive, but I do not know how to check this.

I'll try the following tests:

- Nirsoft ShellExView
- Nirsoft WhatIsHang
- configuring PyCharm to use the Command Prompt instead of Powershell and see if this helps (requires running `anaconda3/Scripts/activate.bat`)

---

**Edit** 2:
I have *no* idea how to use ShellExView. PyCharm does not appear there. And WhatIsHang also doesn't help because nothing actually hangs... the PC does seem to take a long time to register that you wanted to open something. Except for new folders in Explorer.exe, that's still fast.

Setting PyCharm to use `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as the terminal seems to avoid the issue. PyCharm automatically calls Anaconda's `activate.bat` script and correctly activates the conda environment I configured for the project.

I tried creating a shortcut for `powershell.exe` inside a Google Drive synced folder and see if opening the shortcut lead to the same issues, but that did not occur.

Comment: Start your system in a minimal setup.  Have nothing running except what is absolutely required for Windows to properly function.  Additionally, have all files locally in a separate folder, outside of Google Drive.  You might also consider updating Visual Code to the current version.  After you do all that, load a project that you have this problem with, see if the behavior still happen,s and [edit] your question with the results.  I suspect part of the problem is that Google Drive wasn't designed to have git repository contained within it.  There are solutions to that problem though.

Comment: Task Manager takes ages to open    .....   This issue you have is likely a shell context issue.  Try Nirsoft (.net)  Sell View. It may be like trying to find a needle in a haystack.

Comment: I had a problem that prevent Task Manager from opening, it was caused by a specific website within Edge, something about what was happening within Edge caused all sorts of problems.  I couldn't say if my processor was pegged since I never had Task Manager opened, the problem only went away when I close the offending tab. It being in Edge made it difficult to do that for obvious reasons. I also had a bad HDD once, that generated so many I/O errors, keyboard and mouse actions would take 3 minutes to catch up.  The drive ultimately failed, hard, like nothing could be recovered.

Comment: I am still having trouble debugging this... it seems so inconsistent. It will take a while for me to finish all of the tests without delaying work.

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for in ShellExView. I opened it, opened the folder as a PyCharm project, the issue occurred, but nothing changed in ShellExView, from what I could tell